# Compile pycharm project into a single .py file?

Tags: python, compilation, pycharm

I have recently finished my first project in pycharm in which I have multiple pycharm files and am importing between them. I am trying to now compile it all into one big `.py` file as that is what my course has requested me to do. Is there an easy way to do this without having to copy paste between them all?

Every search I have found for compiling in pycharm shows how to compile it to a `.exe`, whereas I want it in one big `.py`file.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "pycharm file". Do you meant python files? If so, then if you want to have everything in one python file, you have to move all the code into the same file & adjust the imports accordingly.

Comment: Copy-paste I'm afraid.

Comment: yes sorry , i meant python file. - @kabanus ok thank you , will do :(